# What's the degree of the following field extension?

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $f(t)=t^4+9t^2+15$ - What is $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q(\alpha ^2+3)\textbf{]}$?

As $f(t)$ is irreducible (Eisenstein $p=3$) $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q]=4$, so by the tower law $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q(\alpha ^2+3)\textbf{]}\in \{1,2, 4\}$.
It can't be $4$ as $\alpha ^2+3$ is not in $\Bbb Q$ but how do I determine if it is $2$ or $1$? Can't seem to be able to figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "it can't be 1 as $\alpha^2 + 3$ is not in $\mathbb Q$". I think you mean that $[\mathbb Q(\alpha^2 + 3) : \mathbb Q]$ cannot be 1 for that reason, and hence $[\mathbb Q(\alpha) : \mathbb Q(\alpha^2 + 3)]$ can't be 4. In order to prove that it can't be 1, you just need to show that the two fields aren't equal.

To do this, observe that $\mathbb Q(\alpha^2 + 3) = \mathbb Q(\alpha^2)$, and $f$ is clearly a quadratic in $\alpha^2$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it can't be 4.
How do you argue that it can't be 1?

Comment: By not thinking it through :)

Comment: @user62729 I suggest you edit your question then.

Comment: (fixed my argument)

Comment: already did, thanks

Answer (score 0):

$\alpha$ satisfies the polynomial $x^2+3-(\alpha^2+3)$ in the field ${\bf Q}(\alpha^2+3)$.

Comment: Do you mean $\alpha$ instead of $a$?

Comment: An earlier version of the question used $a$, seems someone switched it to $\alpha$

Comment: Yeah, I did. Small $a$ isn't a root. It's a coefficient at best.

Comment: OK, I'll go with the flow.